# Is there a GUI for nethogs or similar network-monitoring app?

Tags: gui, network-monitoring

I have this terminal window opened with nethogs running to see what application is using the bandwidth but it would be so much nicer in the bar next to the clock or even in a GUI. Does anything like that exists for Ubuntu? A bit like Little Snitch on the Mac.

Comment: maybe this can solve the problem:
http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=143833
It is a  Plasmoid which uses nethogs as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familar with snitch, but:

https://github.com/akshayKMR/hogwatch - recent HTML based nethogs GUI

http://chozabu.net/autopush/2016-07-16-11-25-428412300.png - screenshot of the network monitor in KDE4 (there is also one for KDE5 and other systems too)

Answer (score 5):

I made simple GKT based GUI for nethogs.
You can find it here: https://github.com/mbfoss/gnethogs